Introduce "competition" tag
We currently have no competition tag. We however do have a SHA-3-competition tag. 
Should we introduce a "competition" tag and then convert the SHA-3-competition tags to that tag (together of course with the SHA-3 tags). That way we can annotate things like: sha-3 nist competition.
We could also keep to the current and just use the name of the competition. This could be more useful for people searching for the thing by name, and you might be able to use fewer tags. However, people may forget to tag it e.g. sha-3 as that is already in the name.

Can you give examples of questions where this tagging is relevant, and what difference it would make for categorization?

Tags indicate what a question is about. If a question is tagged competition, that means it's about competitions. Not that it's about a specific competition. A question about the SHA-3 competition should not be tagged competition, unless it's about running competitions in general and just happens to use SHA-3 as an example.
I don't think we should have a competition tag. Crypto algorithm design competitions are not so frequent that we have questions about how they're run, and running competitions is mostly off-topic here anyway. A question about competitions would have to be specific to crypto competitions to make sense on this site. I think if the tag existed, it would be mostly used by people who are taking part in a capture-the-flag competition.
From the tag FAQ on the main meta:

Tags are for sorting your question into specific, well-defined categories. Each tag should by itself refer to a specific category. If a tag only makes sense when used in combination with another tag (like '2005' with 'sql-server', 'visual' with 'studio', or '3.5' with '.net'), it's a meta tag.


No, please don't introduce the competition tag and use competition-specific tags instead.
There will be few questions tagged with this and more frequent tags may have to be added afterwards.

Yes, please introduce a competition tag so we can use that in combination with the other tags.
People might have to write the competition name in the question title or body if the competition has a non-common name.
